# How to compare two instances of a state in Corda

Tags: corda

I just want to get the changed fields in a state. So what am doing is like am taking the consumed state (which will have the initial state before updating it) and unconsumed state(which will be the latest one with updated fields ) .now i have these two states then what will i do to find the altered fields(field names) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the Reflection to achieve that. Below is the Kotlin code snippet

```
fun compareFields(lineItem1: State1, lineItem2: State1): List<String> {

val differentFieldsNames = ArrayList<String>()
val differentFields = State1::class.memberProperties.filter {

    val startValue = it.get(lineItem1)
    val endValue = it.get(lineItem2)
    !Objects.deepEquals(startValue, endValue)
}
differentFields.forEach {
    println("Fields not matching "+" "+it.name)
    differentFieldsNames.add(it.name)

}
return differentFieldsNames
```

}